# Can Android VideoView play VP8 codec video?

Tags: android, android-videoview, webm, vp8

I have been searching for an answer to this question everywhere. I looked at the supported formats for android and the .webm file I have is supported and it plays on the built-in video player on my android device, yet it won't play in VideoView. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you getting `status code` from mediaplayer while initializing ? If so post it here. Also show your `logcat`.